# How to create a text or xlsx file?

Tags: abap

How to create a text file or xlsx file using ABAP?

Also, what is the difference between,

```
OPEN DATASET filename FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT.
```

and

```
OPEN DATASET filename FOR INPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT.
```

?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In what way is the difference between `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` unclear?

Comment: I was searching the solution in google. In some links, some peoples are suggested to use Input and Output for read and write text files. But as a newcomer into SAP, i couldn't understand the usage of input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'OUTPUT' is for Writing files  and 'INPUT' is for reading in Files.

Refer [SAP help](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapread_dataset.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FM GUI_DOWNLOAD for presentation server i.e local PC or OPEN DATASET for application server.

You can use FM SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING as well to achieve your requirement.

Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634939/how-to-read-text-files-from-content-repository-in-sap-abap/31018082#31018082).