# how to read text files from content repository

Tags: content-management-system, abap, sap-basis

My requirement is read text files from content repository in sap abap.I used `SCMS_DOC_READ` FM to read image file and creating url `DP_CREATE_URL` for creating image url but `SCMS_DOC_READ` not working for text.

Can any one suggest some code, FM or class .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options based on your requirement:

**Option 1:** Use READ DATASET to read file.

```
DATA : FNAME(60) type c VALUE 'myfile.txt',
       TEXT2(5) type c.

       OPEN DATASET FNAME FOR INPUT IN TEXT MODE.

       DO.
        READ DATASET FNAME INTO TEXT2 LENGTH LENG.
        WRITE: / SY-SUBRC, TEXT2.
         IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
             EXIT.
         ENDIF.
      ENDDO.

     CLOSE DATASET FNAME.
```

**Option 2:** Use Class CL_ABAP_CONV_IN_CE to read file.

Refer this [tutorial page](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/CL_ABAP_CONV_IN_CE) to get more information on this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find the answer there: http://scn.sap.com/thread/525075

If you want the short answer, you should use this(Note: I am not the author of this part):

```
CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_UPLOAD'
  EXPORTING
    FILENAME                     = "File path"
    FILETYPE                     = 'ASC'
   HAS_FIELD_SEPARATOR           = 'X'

TABLES
    DATA_TAB                     = IT.
```

Note : Internal table structure should be same as text File.